# using multi-term/ansi-term in emacs -- emacs within emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've read that it is possible to run emacs (remote machine) within emacs (local machine) using multi-term/ansi-term. How do I set up the appropriate key bindings to enable control of the remote emacs? For instance, `C-x C-f` will try to open local files.

Comment: This isn't programming related.  Recommend moving to Superuser.

Comment: Point taken. How can I move it there?

Comment: It'll take a few more close votes.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to use [Tramp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode). This allows you to open remote files from within a local Emacs session. Then you can kill/yank/whatever between local and remote files as if they were all on the same computer. With tramp, you specify at the prompt whether `C-x C-f` should open a local or remote file, and other than that everything else is handled behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks, I do use tramp from time to time. But sometimes when you are already in a terminal shell in a particular directory, it is easy just to type `emacs filename` rather than having to retype the path  to open the file in tramp-mode, and also to run an interactive Python interpreter in the same emacs buffer.

Comment: There's no need to retype the path. Just use remote directory tracking:


http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints#toc4

Comment: Remote directory tracking is interesting... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this question is addressed on the [relevant emacswiki page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultiTerm#toc4).

Comment: Yes, this is where I read that it was possible, but then I would not be able to switch commands between local and remote emacs. I was hoping someone could suggest a configuration that works for him/her.